# how to store cedit card info ( am using stripe )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

So I know there have been numerous posts about storing credit card information. We are building a mobile application and want people to be able to enter in their card information once, not with each purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe had detailed documentation on how this works on their platform. For example you can [save a card during a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment) which lets you accept a $10 charge for example while saving the card for future payments. They also let you [set up future payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) where you collect a card today without any payment and can charge the card late.